# How to convert a curl command in java for android app

Tags: java, android, curl

I am trying to convert a curl command into java to use in my very basic android app. I am very new in this, and lack a lot knowledge. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. The command stands:

```
(echo -n '{"data": "'; base64 dog.14.jpg; echo '"}') | 
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @-  http://ip-address:80
```

Comment: consider using volley or retrofit or any such api's for post request

Comment: here is a good example of getting json data from a service for android apps   http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/